# Does the Fourier transform of $e^{-\epsilon x}$ have a limit in distributional sense?

Tags: real-analysis, fourier-analysis

$F_{\epsilon} =  e^{-\epsilon x}, x\geq 0$ , and it is easy to derive $\hat{F_{\epsilon}}(y) = \frac{1}{\epsilon + i y} $. I wonder whether this function has a limit function when $\epsilon$ tends to $0$.

I want to do the following in order to show its limit exists. Consider its action on a Schwarz function $g$, we have $\int \frac{1}{\epsilon+iy} g(y)dy = \int -i(ln(\epsilon +iy))'g = -i \int g dln(\epsilon +iy)$. This is not a valid argument because logarithm is not properly defined.

Comment: What does that mean? @CharlesMadeline

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $1/y$ be the p.v. functional and let all the limits be for $\epsilon \to 0^+$. The distributional limit exists and can be found in any of these ways:

1) using the Sokhotski-Plemelj formula:
$$\frac 1 {\epsilon + i y} =
\frac i {-y + i \epsilon} \xrightarrow {\mathcal D}
-\frac i y + \pi \delta(y);$$

2) using the fact that the limit and the Fourier transform are interchangeable:
$$e^{-\epsilon x} H(x) \xrightarrow {\mathcal D} H(x), \\
(H(x), e^{-i y x}) =
-\frac i y + \pi \delta(y);$$

3) writing the functionals as distributional derivatives of ordinary functions, as you suggest. The logarithm is an integrable function, therefore it just corresponds to a regular functional. It can be proved that the limit and the derivative of $\ln(\epsilon + i y)$ are the same in the ordinary sense and in the distributional sense, giving

$$\left( \frac 1 {\epsilon + i y}, \phi \right) =
(i \ln(\epsilon + i y), \phi') \to \\
(i \ln(i y), \phi') =
\left( i \ln |y| - \frac \pi 2 \operatorname{sgn} y, \phi' \right) = \\
\left( -\frac i y + \pi \delta(y), \phi \right).$$

Comment: Can you elaborate more on the third approach? In particular, I am confused about how to prove the first step. How do you use integration by part for the complex logarithm? Do we need to choose a branch?

Comment: We can take the principal branch of the logarithm or any other branch for which $\ln(\epsilon + i y)$ is continuous in $y$ on the real line. Then $\ln(\epsilon + i y)$ is smooth, and integration by parts goes through. The second step requires proving that the limit and the integral can be interchanged.

Comment: why is $iln(iy) = iln|y| - \frac{\pi}{2}sgny$? Shouldn't $ln iy = ln|y| + \frac{\pi}{2}i$ since ln z = ln|z| + i argz?

Comment: We're integrating wrt $y$ from $-\infty$ to $\infty$. For real $y$ and for the principal value of the argument, $\arg(\epsilon + i y) \to \pi/2 \operatorname{sgn} y$. The $+\pi$ jump will be the same for any branch which makes $\ln(\epsilon + i y)$ continuous in $y$.